# How can I remove all text AFTER a word in bash, keeping the word

Tags: bash, sorting, text, sed

So, if I have a .txt like this:

```
He.likes.coding
She.likes.juice
He.likes.coffee
```

It becomes:

```
He.likes
She.likes
He.likes
```

So it will keep the special text (.likes)

If there is already a answer for this, I'm sorry, but I didn't find it. All the ones that I found deleted the .likes also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F"likes" '{print $1FS}' file
He.likes
She.likes
He.likes
```

It separate the fields using  `likes`, then print everything before it and the field separator.

---

If there are other lines that should not be changed, use this:

```
awk -F"likes" 'NF>1{$0=$1FS}1' file
```

It will only change line witch has `likes` in it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed.

```
sed 's/\.likes.*/.likes/' file
```

`.*` matches any character except line breaks, zero or more times. Here we don't need to add `g` global flag since a single match happens per line.

**OR**

Use capturing group.

```
sed 's/\(\.likes\).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: add boundary if necessary `sed 's/\(\.likes\)\b.*/\1/' file`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '.*likes' file
```

Output:

```
He.likes
She.likes
He.likes
```

Comment: I do not believe the `P` in `-oP` is necessary in this case as `grep -o '.*likes' file` will return the desired results, at least in BSD or GNU `grep` on the versions I've tested.  Also isn't the `-P` considered highly experimental and `-E` would be better if needed, although in this case isn't `'.*likes'` just a `BRE` and why `-o` by itself will return the desired results?